# Shopware multilanguage catagories

Tags: multilingual, shopware

Please, help. How I can create 2 categories in main and language shop with similar urls?

For example I wanna get for 2 categories `food` and `eaten` links like `food` and `/de/food`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you have an own category-tree for every shop/language. Every shop needs a unique identifier (like virtual url /de or an own domain). In this case everything should work by default, without any additional configuration.

You should have a look at the s_core_rewrites_url and check which urls are created for your case.

Every url needs to be unique - so there is no possibility to get "/food" in the same language twice. By adding a unique identifier like the category-id in the seo/router configuration of the basic settings, you can modify the urls, as explained in the documentation: 
https://en-community.shopware.com/_detail_1143.html

Regenerating SEO-URLs is possible via backend and via CLI

Comment: I saw this article. It was not helpful. So, I'll try to clarify my question. I have multi language shop (en & de versions). En is primary. In en i have `food ` category. In DE I have `eten` category with url `/de/eten`. I want to understand how implement autoswithch from 1 `food` category to `eten`, because when I switch language from `food` Shopware redirect me to `/de/food`.

Comment: This is not possible by default, because those categories have no relation to each other. You need to implement this on your own via plugin.
Shopware 5.5 will offer the possibility to translate categories, with this you can use one category tree and the redirect will work. Currently (SW 5.4) you need to do this on your own.